# Invoke judgment from from within reduction-relation

Tags: racket, plt-redex

I'm working on defining a language which has casts and subtyping as follows:

```
(define-language base 
  (t ::= int any) 
  (e ::= number (cast t e)) 
  #| stuff ... |#)
```

I then define the following judgment form over it:

```
(define-judgment-form base
   #:mode (<: I I)
   #:contract (<: t t)
   [------ 
    (<: t t)]
   [------ 
    (<: int any)])
```

And now, in my reduction relation, I want to write something like

```
(define b-> (reduction-relation base
    (--> (cast t v)
         v
         (where-judgment-holds (<: (typeof v) t)))))
```

Where we assume that `(typeof v)` returns the type of the value `v`. As far as I can tell, there isn't anything like `where-judgment-holds` in the Redex library, and while I can work around it with an unquote, it would be nice if there was something built into Redex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for actually is called `judgment-holds`, and it works in your example exactly where you put `where-judgment-holds`:

```
(define b-> (reduction-relation base
    (--> (cast t v)
         v
         (judgment-holds (<: (typeof v) t)))))
```